# What is precise meaning of replicas attribute in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In documentation of Kubernetes IO, the `replicas` attribute is explained using itself in the definition thus it doesn't give precise information.
Does value `replicas: 1` in yaml means there is 1 pod xor that there are 2 pods: 1 original plus 1 duplicate of it? Is the default 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replicas` is the number of pods that you want the controller i.e., deployment, replicaset or statefulset controller to create from the given `spec.template` pod template. It defaults to 1 if not specified.

`replicas: 1` means 1 pod in total.

Comment: Thank you, that makes it clear. At the same time the name is very misleading, `pods` would be much better.

Answer (score 3):

As explained below `replicas` means desired number of pods.

```
kubectl explain deployment.spec.replicas
KIND:     Deployment
VERSION:  apps/v1

FIELD:    replicas <integer>

DESCRIPTION:
     Number of desired pods. This is a pointer to distinguish between explicit
     zero and not specified. Defaults to 1.
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#deploymentspec-v1beta1-apps

Comment: Could you provide a link please?

Comment: Updated in answer